# Want to print a menu but i started with low dimensions

Tags: print-design, resolution

I designed a menu for a pizza restaurant but it seems that the dimensions and dpi is low. These are the dimensions, could someone tell me if this is okay for printing or not.

- Dimensions: 595x842
- Dpi: 92

Comment: For commercial printing? No, that's **not** okay. Unless your intention is to have a 3x4" menu.

Comment: Hi user46699, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 color printing typically asks for imagery at 300dpi.

If the menu is 8" wide, then you need a horizontal resolution of 8x300 = 2400 pixels.

Note that the above is for imagery (photos, full color illustration, etc.). Text should ideally be set at an absolute minimum of 600dpi, and more preferably 1200dpi+. This is usually done by not setting type in a raster image editing tool like Photoshop, but using a vector based tool such as Illustrator or InDesign. This allows the type to be output at the highest supported resolution the printer supports.

You didn't mention the software you are using, but in general, Photoshop would not be the right tool for designing a menu.

UPDATE:

OK, based on your comments, I see the issue now. What you're being asked to do is to create a raster image of your vector file.

For starters, this is a bad idea and there's no real reason for this. If your client doesn't have Illustrator, you can still send them a vector file--PDF being the most common solution. I'd suggest you just send them the PDF. In fact, if they have a printer, you should be in communication directly with the printer (and nearly every printer should have a copy of Illustrator anyways).

All that said, if you truly must create a raster image for this, then you'll want to do the following:

- Scale your illustrator file to the actual size you wanted it printed at
- Export it as a raster image at a DPI of a minimum 300. Ideally higher if we're talking mostly text (600 or 12000) and at the actual size your image was set at in illustrator.

Comment: Im using illustrator, so i finished this menus like more than half year ago but it seems the dpi and resolution are low because i choosed A4 i thought it would be better but it turns out its not. Everything in the document is vector so if i make another document with good resolution and dpi and if i transfer the design in the new document with stretching with holding shift would be the same or it will lose the shape?

Comment: @user46699 Illustrator vector files don't have resolution. That's the  primary benefit of Illustrator: Vectors are resolution independent.  There's no need to set dpi in illustrator at all (outside of raster effects, which is a different topic...)

Comment: I know for that, but the person who is going to print the menu i dont think that he has illustrator, i guess he need pictures and after he will print them

Comment: @user46699 I think we need more information here. Are you saying the person printing is asking for something like a JPG to print? What software are they using? Are they printing this on a personal printer or going to a print shop?

Comment: Yes he needs jpeg to print, he said he doesnt have illustrator so i have to save menu's in jpeg and send them for a printing. He has his own small company for printing. So if he wants jpegs than i have to make bigger document with good resolution and dpi. I guess it will work with the transfering and stretching way.

Comment: @user46699 I updated the answer with more info. Hope it helps!